# How to write a python program that returns all words that occur at least 5 times in a text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I just need to do what the title of this post says: write a python program that returns all words that occur at least 5 times in a text. I realize this is a pretty simple question. I am a novice programmer trying to pick up some NLP skills and for some reason I can't figure this out. Your help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any code that attempts to solve this problem? If so, please provide it so we can help you learn by providing specific advice. :)

Comment: Hints: read up on `nltk.FreqDist`, if you're using `nltk`, or `collections.Counter`, if you're not.

Answer (score 4):

You should define what do you mean by "word". Different definitions can produce different results. The general template is:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(getwords(normalize(text)))
words = [w for w, c in count.items() if c >= 5]
```

Where you could use various definition of `getwords()`, `normalize()` e.g.:

```
import re

def normalize(text): # remove non-ascii, convert to lowercase
    return text.encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower().decode()

def getwords(text): # allow only a-z
    return re.findall(ur"[a-z]+", text)
```

Or nltk-based tokenizer:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

def getwords(text):
    return (w for sent in sent_tokenizer(text) for w in word_tokenize(sent))
```

Comment: Thanks! I know have a few ways to solve this problem in the future!

Answer (score 3):

How about you tokenize the string as a first step using str.split(). Then, go through the resulting array using a for loop, doing the following: if the word is not contained in the set of keys of a dictionary, add it to the dictionary, storing its count, in this case 1. Otherwise, the word is already contained, look up its count in the dictionary, increment the count, and push it back into the dictionary. Finally, when you are done with counting words, go trough the dictionary and retain only what has a count of five or more.

Comment: Much better off with `nltk` here.

Comment: a great breakdown for the novice without any assumptions about their level of Python ability

Comment: `str.split()` is not very useful for word tokenization: it doesn't recognize "word", "Word", "word." as the same word. There is no need to use a `dict` directly here: there are `collections.Counter`, `collections.defaultdict` (for older Python versions).

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes of Googling would have pointed you to [`nltk`](http://nltk.org/book/ch01.html#bigrams_index_term) and the `FreqDist` class.

```
import nltk
words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
freq1 = nltk.FreqDist(words)
words_above_five_times = [w for w in freq1.keys() if freq1[w] >= 5]
```

Comment: `word_tokenize(sentence)` expects a single sentence as an input. You should tokenize text to extract sentences first. `FreqDist.keys()` returns keys sorted by frequency; so you can break the loop earlier